# How to install a GitHub package after downloading it if there is not any setup.py file

Tags: python, opencv, github

I am trying to install the python package pyimagesearch from GitHub after downloading the package.

I have tried in cmd: `pip install setup.py` but there is not any file named setup.py

My internet speed is slow so cloning is not working for me.

Comment: Is this it?  https://github.com/meizhoubao/pyimagesearch

Comment: Precisely what pyimagesearch package are you referring to?  The one at https://github.com/meizhoubao/pyimagesearch does not appear to be the kind you install.

Comment: yes this is the package I want to use

Comment: @Muhammad: And just how do you expect to use the package?  It does not appear to be meant for installation; at best, it's just a bunch of scripts you can run the same as any other scripts.

Comment: can you tell how to use it

Answer (score -1):

Use exact file path instead of setup.py.
For eg. `pip install entire-path//setup.py` 
This should work.

Comment: i have tried but there is not any file name swtup.py

Comment: i have tried this but there is not any file name setup.py